# Responsive Circles (Max Area while maintaining aspect ratio)

Tags: html, css

Ok so this was confusing the first time I wrote this.  Time to simplify.

Code:

```
<div id="fluid-container">
    <div id="max-circle"></div>
</div>
```

#fluid-container has width's and heights that change independently of each other.

#max-circle is a circle with the largest possible area while staying completely in #fluid-container.  Meaning that if #fluid-container has a large height than width, the diameter of the circle will be the width of #fluid-container, but if it is the other way around (width greater than height), than #max-circle will have a diameter equivalent to #fluid-container's height.

Is this possible?  How would one go about this without using javascript?

EDIT:
Desired Functionality:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV0CT.png

Comment: let me get this straight. You want to have a bubble in the center of the page that is never bigger than the page, but changes size dependent on the page's size?

Comment: @DaMaxContent not really.  Basically, imaging a <div></div> who's height and width can change size independently.  I want to have a circle with the largest possible area while staying completely in the <div>, meaning that if the <div>'s width is bigger, it will use that for it's diameter, but if height is bigger, it will use height.

It makes a lot more sense in my head lol.

Comment: would you be willing to change the div to an iframe? because then you could use media queries to detect if the iframe's height is bigger than its width.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355244/how-can-i-detect-which-window-dimension-is-bigger-just-using-css-media-query/8355677#8355677 refers to the media queries that would be useful

Comment: for this purpose, using @media queries would not be possible, because the container div does not necessarily pertain to the aspect ratio of the document.

Comment: I'll try drawing something up and posting it in the original post.

Comment: not entirely true. if you changed the div to an iframe, it would be with respect to your pseudo-div

Comment: @DaMaxContent I will attempt that, although I am not that much of a fan of using several frames in my document ;)

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: no problem, it is unfortunately the only way for css to detect if a width of an element is greater than the height

Comment: I updated the answer with a fiddle. I reccommend you check it out

Comment: it's not centered, but I am sure with some css positioning tricks, you could make it work

Answer (score 1):

You can use an orientation media query in combination with an iframe instead of a div:

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait) { … }
@media all and (orientation:landscape) { … }
```

From the [W3C media Queries spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation):

> The ‘orientation’ media feature is ‘portrait’ when the value of the ‘height’ media feature is greater than or equal to the value of the ‘width’ media feature. Otherwise ‘orientation’ is ‘landscape’.

Here is an example usage:
circle is 100% of smallest dimension's size

```
<style>
  #fluid-container{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 5px #000 solid
  }
</style>
<!--use srcdoc attribute to insert content into iframe without a url
notice how the style tag and div tag are inside the quotes for the srcdoc attribute-->
<iframe srcdoc="<style>
    body{
      margin:0;
    }
    #max-circle{
      background-color:#000;
      border-radius:50%
    }
    @media all and (orientation:portrait) {
      #max-circle{
        height: 100vw;
        width: 100vw;
      }
    }
    @media all and (orientation:landscape) {
      #max-circle{
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vh;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <div id='max-circle'></div>" id="fluid-container">

</iframe>
```

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w28pgrp6/) for it